# try to merge entity in case of Delete attempt fails and throws exception "foreign key constraint"

Tags: hibernate

Objective : Try to delete a Row from Database and it its linked to some another table as Foreign Key, merge entity with status inactive

In finally block am trying to merge entity but it throws exception 
Code :

```
public void deleteServiceData(Service service) {
        boolean deleteServiceException = false;
        Service entity = null;
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            if (service != null) {
                 entity = getServiceMasterId(service);
                 em.remove(entity);
                 em.flush();
                 logger.info("Deleted");
            }
        }catch(PersistenceException e) {
            logger.error("There is an PersistenceException");
            deleteServiceException = true;
            em.clear();
        }catch(Exception e) {
            logger.error("There is an Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally{
            logger.info("finally block execution"+deleteServiceException);
            if(deleteServiceException == true){
                Service ser = entity; 
                ser.setStatus(StatusEnum.I);
                logger.info("Service ready to delete");
                em = emf.createEntityManager();
                em.merge(ser);
                em.flush();
            }
        }
```

Exception:

```
 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`devbackup`.`section`, CONSTRAINT `FKA03B0AC53771DF5C` FOREIGN KEY (`SERVICE_ID`) REFERENCES `service` (`ID`))
18:11:28,817 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl] (default task-59) HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
18:11:28,817 ERROR [com.icare.scheduling.ejb.ServiceEJBImpl] (default task-59) There is an PersistenceException
18:11:28,817 INFO  [com.icare.scheduling.ejb.ServiceEJBImpl] (default task-59) finally block executiontrue
18:11:28,817 INFO  [com.icare.scheduling.ejb.ServiceEJBImpl] (default task-59) Service ready to delete
18:11:28,818 INFO  [stdout] (default task-59) Hibernate: select service0_.ID as ID1_59_0_ _ from SERVICE service0_

18:11:28,818 WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-59) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
18:11:28,818 ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-59) javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000460: Error checking for a transaction
18:11:28,818 INFO  [org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener] (default task-59) HHH000327: Error performing load command : org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
18:11:28,821 ERROR [com.icare.rest.scheduling.ServiceImpl] (default task-59) There is an Exception
18:11:28,821 ERROR [stderr] (default task-59) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection

18:11:28,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-59)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)

18:11:28,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-59)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)

18:11:28,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-59)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)

18:11:28,822 ERROR [stderr] (default task-59)   at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1206)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Service entity has a reference to some other entity, without the tables, I am not sure what that is, looks like section.  Assuming you also want to remove that reference you need to do one of the following:

- delete the reference in the other table first
- remove the foreign key constraints

  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
- setup cascading deletes which would looks something like:

  ALTER TABLE `Service`

  ADD CONSTRAINT `service_ibfk_1`

  FOREIGN KEY (`service_id`) REFERENCES `section` (`service_id`)

  ON DELETE CASCADE;

It's possible that this relationship is actually the inverse of what you want (delete that other entity and cascade delete Service) depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: Section table has a foreign key to Service. Am trying to delete a row which is linked in section table. In that case FOREIGN  CONSTRAINT  error shows up.. Now what i want is if exception occurs than i have to update service table with a field status as I for inactive .... when i try to update it shows above warning.... I dont want to delete all the linked record